# Python debugging in Netbeans

Tags: python, netbeans

I have a problem with debugging Python programs under the Netbeans IDE. When I start debugging, the debugger writes the following log and error. Thank you for help.

```
[LOG]PythonDebugger : overall Starting
>>>[LOG]PythonDebugger.taskStarted : I am Starting a new Debugging Session ...
[LOG]This window is an interactive debugging context aware Python Shell
[LOG]where you can enter python console commands while debugging
>>>c:\documents and settings\aster\.netbeans\6.7\config\nbpython\debug\nbpythondebug\jpydaemon.py
args = ['C:\\Documents and Settings\\aster\\.netbeans\\6.7\\config\\nbPython\\debug\\nbpythondebug\\jpydaemon.py', 'localhost', '11111']
localDebuggee= None
JPyDbg connecting localhost on in= 11111 /out= 11112
ERROR:JPyDbg connection failed errno(10061) : Connection refused
Debug session normal end

ERROR :: Server Socket listen for debuggee has timed out (more than 20 seconds wait) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
```

thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Python for NetBeans yesterday and hadn't tried the debugger, so just tried it, and I got the same error. So I thought maybe it's a Firewall issue, disabled my Firewall and retried it, and then it worked.

However I restarted the Firewall and now it's still working, so I don't know. I saw the Netbeans options for Python have an input to specify the beginning listening port (which mine was 29000 not 11111 like yours).

Answer (score 1):

For Python I like WingIDE from Wingware.